# Wide range of protocols one chip?

Tags: arduino-ide

Is there some way to do raw radio on a esp32 and change frequencies. If not what would I need to transmit rf, wifi, bluetooth, zigbee etc. There seems to be no tutorials on how to do anything of the sort.

Comment: search for `SDR software-defined radio`

Answer (score 1):

> There seems to be no tutorials on how to do anything of the sort.

That's because doing such a thing is not something the manufacturer of a part typically expects you to want to do. Yes, some chips may be capable of other protocols internally, but making them use those protocols would mean direct manipulation of the low level components in the chip.

Chips like the ESP32 or the nRF24L01 are geared towards specific protocols. They expose functionality that is good for those protocols.

There are other chips which are designed with (almost) any protocol in mind, but there's nothing "arudinoy" about using them. To access other protocols you would download the SDK for that chip and create new firmware specifically for the protocol you want to use. In many cases such SDKs and the associated documentation is protected under NDA so you or I getting access to such a thing is not usually possible.

In general though a chip is designed with a specific protocol and application in mind and is optimised specifically to handle the requirements of that protocol.